# How can do find inside object using javascript?

Tags: javascript

we have 3 brandnames nokia ,samsung ,iphone and

This is my object

```
var list ={

    nokia: [

            {name:"Nokia 150",id:"11"},
            {name:"Nokia X5",id:"12"},
            {name:"Nokia 216",id:"0"},
            {name:"Nokia 130",id:"13"}

    ],
    samsung:[

        {name:"Galaxy J5", "id":"21"},
            {name:"Galaxy Grand","id":"0"}

    ],
    iphone:[

            {name:"iphone 5","id":"31"},
            {name:"iphone 6","id":"32"}

    ]

}
```

i want to find these two condition inside object

```
var searchBrandName = "nokia";

var id ="0";
```

if we find match we need to return true otherwise we need to return false

for above condtion we have match so we need to return true

```
nokia: [
    {name:"Nokia 216",id:"0"},
]
```

if i pass

```
var searchBrandName = "iphone";

var id ="0";
```

we dont have match we need to return false

how to do this help me out

Comment: `list[searchBrandName ].find(x => x.id == id)` It will return `null`  if element not found

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any attempts made?

Comment: [Javascript Objects - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` function like:

```
var searchBrandName = "nokia";

var id ="0";
var list ={

nokia: [

        {name:"Nokia 150",id:"11"},
        {name:"Nokia X5",id:"12"},
        {name:"Nokia 216",id:"0"},
        {name:"Nokia 130",id:"13"}

],
samsung:[

    {name:"Galaxy J5", "id":"21"},
        {name:"Galaxy Grand","id":"0"}

],
iphone:[

        {name:"iphone 5","id":"31"},
        {name:"iphone 6","id":"32"}

]

}
var found = list[searchBrandName].some(function (el) {
    return el.id == id;
});
console.log(found);
```

Found will be `true` or `false` depending on the match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```js
var list ={

    nokia: [

            {name:"Nokia 150",id:"11"},
            {name:"Nokia X5",id:"12"},
            {name:"Nokia 216",id:"0"},
            {name:"Nokia 130",id:"13"}

    ],
    samsung:[

        {name:"Galaxy J5", "id":"21"},
            {name:"Galaxy Grand","id":"0"}

    ],
    iphone:[

            {name:"iphone 5","id":"31"},
            {name:"iphone 6","id":"32"}

    ]

}

function searchData(barandName, id) {
  return list[barandName].find(item => {if(item.id === id)return item});
}

var result = searchData("nokia","0");
console.log(result);
```